# gluCylinder with rotated texture

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, glu

I want to draw a cylinder using gluQuadric and gluCylinder.
This cylinder shall be textured.

My draw code is the following:

```
pTexture->Enable();
pTexture->Bind();
glPushMatrix();
glRotatef(-90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

gluQuadricOrientation(quadric, GLU_OUTSIDE);
gluQuadricNormals(quadric, true);
gluQuadricTexture(quadric, true);
gluCylinder(quadric, getRadius(), getRadius(), getHeight(), 16, 1);

glPopMatrix();
pTexture->Unbind();
pTexture->Disable();
```

My problem with this is now, that the texture is rotated 90 degrees. How can I rotate the uv-mapping of the quadric?

The texture is used in other places and thus cannot be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the more widely used `GL_MODELVIEW` and `GL_PROJECTION` matrix stacks, there is also a `GL_TEXTURE` matrix stack that can be used to apply transformations to texture coordinates. For example, this will rotate the texture coordinates by 90 degrees:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Since texture coordinates are normally in a [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0] unit square, using only this might have undesired side effects. The rotation is counter-clockwise around the origin, so our unit square will be rotated to a square with an extent of [-1.0, 0.0] x [0.0, 1.0]. So in addition to the rotation, the square was shifted by (0.0, -1.0). This is harmless if the wrap mode is `GL_REPEAT`, but would bad when using a wrap mode like `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. We can correct for this by applying a translation in the opposite direction after the rotation (remember that the transformation specified last is the one applied first):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Also, depending on what orientation your image is, you may have to rotate by -90 degrees instead. In this case, the unit square with extent [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0] will be rotated into a square with extent [0.0, 1.0] x [-1.0, 0.0]. Applying the same type of corrective translation for this case, we end up with:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glTranslatef(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but rotating +90 degrees resultet in a cylinder with just one color. Rotating -90 degrees works fine und it looks as desired.

Comment: Hmm, yes, since texture coordinates are in the range [0.0, 1.0] range, rotating them around the origin might give you surprising results, since they would end up outside that range. It would probably be fine if your wrap mode is `GL_REPEAT`. Otherwise, you might have to add some translations. I might update the answer later today to elaborate on that some more.