# OpenGL ES Rotate 2D texture

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

I am very new to OpenGL. I am building a painting application on iPad and I am somewhat following Apple's [GLPaint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) example. Basically I want to draw a texture to a position of touch every time touch is moved. I was able to load a texture from an image and draw it to view using the following code:

Init GL:

```
- (BOOL)initGL {

glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(id<EAGLDrawable>)self.layer];
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
    return NO;
}

glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);

brushTexture = [self textureFromName:@"Brush2.png"];

[self setupShaders];

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

return YES;
}
```

Load texture:

```
- (textureInfo_t)textureFromName:(NSString *)name {
CGImageRef      brushImage;
CGContextRef    brushContext;
GLubyte         *brushData;
size_t          width, height;
GLuint          texId;
textureInfo_t   texture;

brushImage = [UIImage imageNamed:name].CGImage;

width = CGImageGetWidth(brushImage);
height = CGImageGetHeight(brushImage);

if(brushImage) {
    brushData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width * height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    brushContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(brushData, width, height, 8, width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(brushImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(brushContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)width, (CGFloat)height), brushImage);

    CGContextRelease(brushContext);
    glGenTextures(1, &texId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)width, (int)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, brushData);

    free(brushData);

    texture.id = texId;
    texture.width = (int)width;
    texture.height = (int)height;
}

return texture;
}
```

Shaders:

```
- (void)setupShaders {
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PROGRAMS; i++)
{
    char *vsrc = readFile(pathForResource(program[i].vert));
    char *fsrc = readFile(pathForResource(program[i].frag));
    GLsizei attribCt = 0;
    GLchar *attribUsed[NUM_ATTRIBS];
    GLint attrib[NUM_ATTRIBS];
    GLchar *attribName[NUM_ATTRIBS] = {
        "inVertex",
    };
    const GLchar *uniformName[NUM_UNIFORMS] = {
        "MVP", "pointSize", "vertexColor", "texture",
    };

    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ATTRIBS; j++)
    {
        if (strstr(vsrc, attribName[j]))
        {
            attrib[attribCt] = j;
            attribUsed[attribCt++] = attribName[j];
        }
    }

    glueCreateProgram(vsrc, fsrc,
                      attribCt, (const GLchar **)&attribUsed[0], attrib,
                      NUM_UNIFORMS, &uniformName[0], program[i].uniform,
                      &program[i].id);
    free(vsrc);
    free(fsrc);

    if (i == PROGRAM_POINT)
    {
        glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);

        glUniform1i(program[PROGRAM_POINT].uniform[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);

        GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, backingWidth, 0, backingHeight, -1, 1);
        GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity; // this sample uses a constant identity modelView matrix
        GLKMatrix4 MVPMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

        glUniformMatrix4fv(program[PROGRAM_POINT].uniform[UNIFORM_MVP], 1, GL_FALSE, MVPMatrix.m);

        glUniform1f(program[PROGRAM_POINT].uniform[UNIFORM_POINT_SIZE], brushTexture.width / kBrushScale);

        glUniform4fv(program[PROGRAM_POINT].uniform[UNIFORM_VERTEX_COLOR], 1, brushColor);
    }
}

glError();
```

}

Draw:

```
- (void)renderLineFromPoint:(CGPoint)start toPoint:(CGPoint)end {
static GLfloat*     vertexBuffer = NULL;
static NSUInteger   vertexMax = 64;
NSUInteger          vertexCount = 0,
                    count,
                    i;

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
start.x *= scale;
start.y *= scale;
end.x *= scale;
end.y *= scale;

if(vertexBuffer == NULL)
    vertexBuffer = malloc(vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));

count = MAX(ceilf(sqrtf((end.x - start.x) * (end.x - start.x) + (end.y - start.y) * (end.y - start.y)) / kBrushPixelStep), 1);
for(i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    if(vertexCount == vertexMax) {
        vertexMax = 2 * vertexMax;
        vertexBuffer = realloc(vertexBuffer, vertexMax * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat));
    }

    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 0] = start.x + (end.x - start.x) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexBuffer[2 * vertexCount + 1] = start.y + (end.y - start.y) * ((GLfloat)i / (GLfloat)count);
    vertexCount += 1;
}

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), vertexBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glUseProgram(program[PROGRAM_POINT].id);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, (int)vertexCount);

glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

}

What I am missing is a method to rotate the texture before each time it gets drawn. I tried to initialize the texture with a rotated CGContext but this take too much processing to call every time a point is drawn. Can someone please show me a better way to rotate the texture. I am very new to OpenGL, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply transformations to the texture coordinates by using the `GL_TEXTURE` matrix mode. For example, to rotate the texture coordinates by 90 degrees counter-clockwise around the z-axis:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Note the translation to keep the texture coordinate ranges within the [0.0, 1.0] range after rotating around the origin. My earlier answer to a similar question here explains some of this in more detail: [gluCylinder with rotated texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556114/glucylinder-with-rotated-texture/24556758#24556758).

I normally try to avoid recommending different technologies than what the posters ask about, but I can't help it in this case: If you're new to OpenGL ES, I would strongly recommend to skip ES 1.x. I believe most people would consider it an obsolete API by now. For example, if you navigate to Man Pages on www.khronos.com (https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/), you will notice that there is no link to ES 1.x anymore. The content is of course still around if you navigate some more, but it's a clear hint that ES 2.0 is considered the baseline these days.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting an answer. However a little confused about the code above. I tried putting it right before the the glDrawArrays function but there is no result. The texture still gets drawn at the original orientation. Should the code go somewhere else?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you're not explicitly setting texture coordinates anywhere. Must be that `GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES` stuff generating them for you. Possible that the texture transformation is not applied to those generated texture coordinates.

Comment: Per the documentation, http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_point_sprite.txt , point sprites are always axis-aligned in window coordinates. The poster will need to switch to using actual geometry rather than an extension intended for particles.

Comment: @Tommy How would I go about doing that? Can you please point me in the right direction? Sorry for my noobiness

Comment: Draw quads with positions and texture coordinates instead of points. Or use ES 2.0. :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi OK, I coded it to work with ES 2.0 :)
Now, how can I rotate?